# I'm trying to have top right border image with a background color

Tags: html, css, background-image

So, I have several position background images in place and a background color and the images have a transparent edge, and I'm wondering if I can eradicate the background color from where the images are transparent.

I currently get this [Image](http://bit.ly/SBUuRg).

And would like to get something like this [Image](http://bit.ly/SHbaFF).

P.S. Sorry for just posting images as links, but at the time of this posting I wasn't allowed to actually post images.

Web Page: desertednoir.uhostfull.com

Relevant Code:

```
#content {
    padding: 1.5%;
    float: left;
    width: 73%;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
    color: Silver;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: url("/images/e_bl.png") no-repeat left bottom,
    url("/images/e_tr.png") no-repeat right top,
    url("/images/e_tc.png") no-repeat center top,
    url("/images/e_br.png") no-repeat right bottom,
    #3C3C3C;
}
```

<div id="content">Content Stuff</div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML and CSS alone are not sufficient to edit an image to add or remove transparent pixels.  However, they also won't **add** color, unless you tell them to.  Just make sure that you **don't** have a `background-color` specified on your element, and it will remain transparent.

I've put your example code into http://jsfiddle.net/XQumV/. As you can see, if you remove `,
    #3C3C3C` from the end of your `background` rule, then your element is transparent.

Because elements in HTML are inherently rectangular, their background-colors will always be rectangular too. Instead of using `background-image` to do get a complex background image, try using `border-image`.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-image for details.

Comment: I'm fine with using JavaScript or anything like that to  resolve the problem. Also, I have a background-color specified, because the only images I use are like 20x20px and just assigned to the corner of the content element.

Comment: Please post all relevant HTML and CSS in your question.

Comment: Updated answer based on your info.  FYI, people will always have an easier time answering your question if you provide a small relevant example in the question; better still if it's in a JSFiddle.